# IOS Push Notification Error

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to develope PushNotification app for IOS. I download the sample code from IBM Getting Started Tutorials. I create NativeAPi Project in IOS and copy the file of sample project in this project. My IBM worklight version is 5.0.5. When i deploy this project in Native API but its giving these error in console:

```
   Activating Worklight project: IOS...
```

[2013-03-28 16:59:56]             Worklight Server stopped successfully on localhost:8080

[2013-03-28 16:59:57]             Worklight Server started successfully on localhost:8080

[2013-03-28 16:59:58] FWLST0011E: ====== Worklight Project IOS-project-customization failed to start: Class 'com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule' defined in login module 'rejectAll' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.

[2013-03-28 16:59:58]             Activation failed. Bundle didn't start:C:\Users\Mohsin\workspace3\IOS\bin\IOS-customization.jar

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html (where I assume you got your sample code) are intended for Worklight V5.0.6.  You will receive the error you saw when you try to use a V5.0.6 sample with an older version of Worklight (v5.0.5 in your case).  Your best bet is to update to V5.0.6.

Comment: If working with an older version, you can find samples by following the link to "Previous versions" at the top of getting started page -- because of bug fixes etc. though I highly recommend updating your Worklight version instead.